# Remove Duplicates keep record with value in specific field

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a table where FieldA,FieldB and FieldC are identical. I want to keep the record `where FieldD is NOT NULL`.

I generally remove duplicates (and prevent future ones) like so:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; 
INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable group by FieldA,FieldB,FieldC;
Drop Table oldtable;
Alter Table newtable RENAME oldtable;
CREATE Unique INDEX UniqueIndex ON oldtable (FieldA,FieldB,FieldC)
```

However I am unclear how to modify this to include the Not Null FieldD. It occurs to me I could use a Max(Char_Length(FieldD) but that simply seems to return the max value for each group, not the record with the max valule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I did the following though not (IMHO) a perfect solution

```
Update Table1 as T1
Inner Join Table1 as T2
On T1.FieldA=T2.FieldA
And T1.FieldB=T2.FieldB
And T1.Field=T2.FieldC
Set T1.FieldD=T2.FieldD
Where T1.FieldD is NULL and T2.FieldD is NOT NULL
```

This allowed me to standardize FieldD to a single non-null value and then I was able to easily remove dupes using the sequence I posted above:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; 
INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable group by FieldA,FieldB,FieldC;
Drop Table oldtable;
Alter Table newtable RENAME oldtable;
CREATE Unique INDEX UniqueIndex ON oldtable (FieldA,FieldB,FieldC)
```

In an ideal world I'd have figured out an update query to remove the dupes per the question but this intermediary step worked fine for now.

Leaving the question open and unsolved in case someone has a more direct solution to my question.